# Why Laravel Jetstream User Profile page is not reflecting any changes?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Jetstream for building a backend portal. However when I am trying to make any changes in the UI level from the user profile page, nothing is getting reflected. Can anyone help regarding this? I am trying to change any content in "resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php". However nothing is getting reflected.

### web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: run  `npm run watch` on terminal while working with the compiled css

Comment: Can you help me which view page does inertia call? I can't locate the location of the resource file. Actually, after login, the UserProfileController.php page is getting hit which is located under vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/http/controllers/Inertia. But I cannot find the view page.

Comment: The code is showing like: return Jetstream::inertia()->render($request, 'Profile/Show', [
            'sessions' => $this->sessions($request)->all(),
        ]);
But I do not know where the view file is located

Comment: you can see these files in `resources/js/componenets`  like this dir